# How to split Android activity in two part and part - 1 must be scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout

I want activity in which part one is scrollable and part two remains still.

[image]

Comment: You can use scrollview with your preffered size

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vertical Linear layout as the parent with two children.

Child 1 - Scrollview with weight 1

Child 2 - A view with height as wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

use something along the lines of this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#abc">
        <!--some content for scrolling here-->
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cba">
        <!--put other component here-->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

here the ScrollView has a layout weight of 3 vs 1 for the LinearLayout so it will take 75% of height and 25% will be given to LinearLayout